# Extract panda dataframe from .xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xml.etree

I have a .xml file with following contents:

```
<detailedreport xmlns:xsi="http://"false">
<severity level="5">
<category categoryid="3" categoryname="Buffer Overflow" pcirelated="false">
<cwe cweid="121" cwename="Stack-based Buffer Overflow" pcirelated="false" sans="120" certc="1160">
<description>
<text text="code."/>
</description>
<staticflaws>
<flaw severity="5" categoryname="Stack-based Buffer Overflow" count="1" issueid="6225" module="Jep" type="strcpy" description="This call to strcpy() contains a buffer overflow. The source string has an allocated size of 80 bytes " note="" cweid="121" remediationeffort="2" exploitLevel="0" categoryid="3" pcirelated="false">
<exploitability_adjustments>
<exploitability_adjustment score_adjustment="0">
</exploitability_adjustment>
</exploitability_adjustments>
</flaw>
</staticflaws>
</cwe>
</category>
</severity>
</detailedreport>
```

Below is the python program to extract some of the fields from the .xml file under the "flaw" tag. But when I print the fields in python program, they are empty.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(r'fps_change.xml')
xroot = root.getroot()

df_cols = ["categoryname", "issueid", "module"]
rows = []

for node in xroot:
    #s_name = node.attrib.get("name")
    s_categoryname = node.find("categoryname")
    s_issueid = node.find("issueid")
    s_module = node.find("module")

rows.append({"categoryname": s_categoryname,
             "issueid": s_issueid, "module": s_module})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
print(out_df)             #this prints empty.
```

Expected Output:

```
 Stack-based Buffer Overflow 6225 Jep
```

What changes should I do in my program to get my expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_obj = BeautifulSoup(string)
flaw = html_obj.find('flaw')
[flaw[key] for key in df_cols]

['Stack-based Buffer Overflow', '6225', 'Jep']
```

---

```
string = '''
<detailedreport xmlns:xsi="http://"false">
<severity level="5">
<category categoryid="3" categoryname="Buffer Overflow" pcirelated="false">
<cwe cweid="121" cwename="Stack-based Buffer Overflow" pcirelated="false" sans="120" certc="1160">
<description>
<text text="code."/>
</description>
<staticflaws>
<flaw severity="5" categoryname="Stack-based Buffer Overflow" count="1" issueid="6225" module="Jep" type="strcpy" description="This call to strcpy() contains a buffer overflow. The source string has an allocated size of 80 bytes " note="" cweid="121" remediationeffort="2" exploitLevel="0" categoryid="3" pcirelated="false">
<exploitability_adjustments>
<exploitability_adjustment score_adjustment="0">
</exploitability_adjustment>
</exploitability_adjustments>
</flaw>
</staticflaws>
</cwe>
</category>
</severity>
</detailedreport>'''
```